# Scrapy INSERT into "new_table" only if records do not exist in "current table"

Tags: python, mysql, scrapy

I tried some website scrapping. I success scraped datas in my current db table. But I would like to INSERT into "new_table" only if records do not exist in "current table"

My code is (pipelines)

```
table = 'products'
table2 = 'new_products'`
def save(self, row): 

    
    cursor = self.cnx.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT DISTINCT product_id FROM products;")
    old_ids = [row[0] for row in cursor.fetchall()]
    create_query = ("INSERT INTO " + self.table + 
        "(rowid, date, listing_id, product_id, product_name, price, url) "
        "VALUES (%(rowid)s, %(date)s, %(listing_id)s, %(product_id)s, %(product_name)s, %(price)s, %(url)s)")

    cursor.execute(create_query, row)
    lastRecordId = cursor.lastrowid

    self.cnx.commit()
    cursor.close()
    print("Item saved with ID: {}" . format(lastRecordId))

    if not product_id in old_ids:
        create_query = ("INSERT INTO " + self.table2 + 
            "(rowid, date, listing_id, product_id, product_name, price, url) "
            "VALUES (%(rowid)s, %(date)s, %(listing_id)s, %(product_id)s, %(product_name)s, %(price)s, %(url)s)")
```

it's not working and I got errors.

```
2022-05-06 12:26:57 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error processing {'date': '2022-05-06 12:26:57.575507',
 'listing_id': '0190199600119',
 'price': '4199.00',
 'product_id': '1209298',
 'product_name': 'APPLE 11" Magic Türkçe Q Klavye Siyah',
 'rowid': 456274953331128512,
 'url': 'https://www.mediamarkt.com.tr/tr/product/APPLE%2011%22%20Magic%20T%C3%BCrk%C3%A7e%20Q%20Klavye%20Siyah-1209298.html'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 654, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 162, in f
    return deferred_from_coro(coro_f(*coro_args, **coro_kwargs))
  File "/root/teknosa/teknosa/pipelines.py", line 28, in process_item
    self.save(dict(item))
  File "/root/teknosa/teknosa/pipelines.py", line 62, in save
    if not product_id in old_ids:
NameError: name 'product_id' is not defined
Saving item into db ...
```

I have unique product_id.

if not product_id in current_table INSERT this product_id to the "new_products"

How to make this?

Thank you.

last edit: I got this error.

```
    2022-05-07 18:17:11 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error processing {'date': '2022-05-07 18:17:11.902622',
 'listing_id': '8713439219357',
 'price': '99.00',
 'product_id': '1175529',
 'product_name': 'TRUST 21935 NANGA USB 3.1 Kart Okuyucu',
 'rowid': -411152717288573423,
 'url': 'https://www.mediamarkt.com.tr/tr/product/TRUST%2021935%20NANGA%20USB%203.1%20Kart%20Okuyucu-1175529.html'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 523, in cmd_query
    self._cmysql.query(query,
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Duplicate entry '-411152717288573423' for key 'products.rowid'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 654, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 162, in f
    return deferred_from_coro(coro_f(*coro_args, **coro_kwargs))
  File "/root/teknosa/teknosa/pipelines.py", line 28, in process_item
    self.save(dict(item))
  File "/root/teknosa/teknosa/pipelines.py", line 69, in save
    cursor.execute(create_query, row)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py", line 269, in execute
    result = self._cnx.cmd_query(stmt, raw=self._raw,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 528, in cmd_query
    raise errors.get_mysql_exception(exc.errno, msg=exc.msg,
mysql.connector.errors.IntegrityError: 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '-411152717288573423' for key 'products.rowid'
```

Comment: It would be very helpful to know which errors you are getting. So, please post your errors + traceback.

Comment: @PatrickKlein I added errors + traceback.

Comment: Your problem is not with SQL, it is in *if not product_id in old_ids:* your product_id variable does not exist

Answer (score 0):

If you want to INSERT only if it does not exist, you don´t need to do what you are doing.There is no need to select all and then look if the one you are looking exists.

What you need is makinq a unique index for **produc_id** in table2

Then change your code to:

```
table = 'products'
table2 = 'new_products'`

def save(self, row):  
    create_query = ("INSERT INTO " + self.table + 
        "(rowid, date, listing_id, product_id, product_name, price, url) "
        "VALUES (%(rowid)s, %(date)s, %(listing_id)s, %(product_id)s, %(product_name)s, %(price)s, %(url)s)")

    cursor.execute(create_query, row)
    lastRecordId = cursor.lastrowid

    self.cnx.commit()
    print("Item saved with ID: {}" . format(lastRecordId))
    create_query = ("INSERT INTO " + self.table2 + 
            "(rowid, date, listing_id, product_id, product_name, price, url) "
            "VALUES (%(rowid)s, %(date)s, %(listing_id)s, %(product_id)s, %(product_name)s, %(price)s, %(url)s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE product_id=product_id")
    cursor.execute(create_query, row)
    self.cnx.commit()
```

If you use ON DUPLICATE KEY, when it finds a duplicate row (a product_id that already exists) the system tryes to update the product_id to the same product_id, so it takes no effect.

And you can remove those commit if you set autocommit= True.

**EDIT**

If as you say in your comment, you need to insert in the new table only if it does not exist in your table, you can change your code like this:

You need to change the name of the variable in the line *old_ids = [row[0] for row in cursor.fetchall()]* because you are changing the value of your `row` parameter
2. Your problem is in the if statement, the product_id variable doesn´t exist, you need to change it

```
table = 'products'
table2 = 'new_products'`

def save(self, row):     
    cursor = self.cnx.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT DISTINCT product_id FROM products;")
    old_ids = [element[0] for element in cursor.fetchall()]
    create_query = ("INSERT INTO " + self.table + 
        "(rowid, date, listing_id, product_id, product_name, price, url) "
        "VALUES (%(rowid)s, %(date)s, %(listing_id)s, %(product_id)s, %(product_name)s, %(price)s, %(url)s)")

    cursor.execute(create_query, row)
    lastRecordId = cursor.lastrowid

    self.cnx.commit()
    cursor.close()
    print("Item saved with ID: {}" . format(lastRecordId))

 

   if not row['product_id'] in old_ids:
        create_query = ("INSERT INTO " + self.table2 + 
            "(rowid, date, listing_id, product_id, product_name, price, url) "
            "VALUES (%(rowid)s, %(date)s, %(listing_id)s, %(product_id)s, %(product_name)s, %(price)s, %(url)s)")
```

Comment: thanks for reply. But I dont need this. My problem is, if scrapy found new item from website, insert into the new_products

Comment: please see my update in my post

Comment: You still have rowid as duplicate, you should modify the value or set as not unique in your DB